# Change Size DatePicker JavaFX - Librarian JFoenix

Tags: java, css, javafx, jfoenix

I have a problem with date-picker librarian JFoenix. He is very a big how can reduce his size?

[enter image description here] -- >> https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtXOj.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your scene.

```
.date-picker-popup .calendar-grid {
    -fx-pref-width: 220.0;
    -fx-pref-height: 180.0;
}
.date-picker-popup .spinner-label {
    -fx-font-size: 14.0;
}
```